# A matrix inequality involving pseudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

I am trying to solve a problem in the context of signal processing, which leads to the following question. Consider two positive definite Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, and a full cloumn rank matrix $W$ with more rows than columns. Assume $B \succ A$, which means $B-A$ is positive definite. Let $C=AW$, and $D=BW$. I want to prove the following inequality $$CC^+ \succ DD^+.$$ Here $C^+$ refers to $C^+=(C^HC)^{-1}C^H$. However, I didn't find any good approach to this proof. Is this inequality true? In addition, I also wonder if other necessary conditions on the involving matrices are needed.

Comment: Thanks for this information, @AVK. I forgot to mention that ***W*** is not  a square matrix. Now I've added it into the question statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2&0\\0&2
\end{array}\right),\quad 
B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\0&1
\end{array}\right),\quad 
W=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0
\end{array}\right).
$$
We have
$$
C=AW=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2\\0
\end{array}\right),\quad
D=BW=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\0
\end{array}\right),
$$
$$
C^{+}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac12 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad
D^{+}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0
\end{array}\right),
$$
$$
CC^{+}=DD^{+}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\0&0
\end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks for this example. Actually, I found that there was something wrong in the previous question, the condition should be $B \succ A$. Afterall, this example still illustrates the problem. Furthermore, I might trace back to the proof of a more general question, which is the origin of the stated one, see (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3052118/proving-a-matrix-inequality-involving-a-extended-matrix-and-the-pseudoinverse-in).